# Long-running script on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I'm attempting to create a microservice on Google App Engine that **is not** intended to handle HTTP requests.

Instead, I was hoping to have a continuously running Python script that monitors a remote queue--[RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/), to be precise--and sends out an api-call to another service as tasks are pushed to the queue.

I was wondering, firstly, is it possible to run a script upon deployment--one that did not originate with a user action/request?

Secondly, how would I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: What's wrong with you triggering this request after the deployment? Either manually, or through a cron job?

Comment: @AndreiVolgin, no fatal defect to use cron or whatever, but, given the OP's exact requirements, isn't it a more natural architecture to serve /_ah/start instead? After all, this use case IS about half the reason it exists (for manual scaled modules).

Comment: @Alex: Starting a manual scaling instance is a "user action" too :)  I like your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can deploy your "script" as a manually scaled module -- see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/ -- with exactly one instance. As the docs say, "When you start a manual scaling instance, App Engine immediately sends a /_ah/start request to each instance"; so, just set that module's handler for /_ah/start to the handler you want to run (in the module's yaml file and the WSGI app in the Python code, using whatever lightweight framework you like -- webapp2, falcon, flask, bottle, or whatever else... the framework won't be doing much for you in this case save the one-off routing).

Note that the number of free machine hours for manual scaling modules is limited to 8 hours per day (for the smaller, B1 instance class; proportionally fewer for larger instance classes), so you may need to upgrade to paid-app status if you need to run for more than 8 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Like @brant said, App Engine is designed to handle HTTP requests. It's not a perfect fit for background jobs, unless you try to wrap your logic into one http request.

Further, App Engine will emit an error when the response timeout, depending on your scaling settings. If you want to try it, [consider basic or manual scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/php/how-instances-are-managed#timeout).

For this type of workload, I would suggest you use a VM.

Answer (score -1):

I think there are a few problems with this design.

First, App Engine is designed to be an HTTP request processor, not a RabbitMQ message processor.  GAE is intended for many small requests, not one long-running process.

Second, "[RabbitMQ should not be exposed to the public internet, it wasn't created for such use case.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/rabbitmq-users/2Li0qdMP--o/TJL-2HaN4XgJ)"

I would recommend that you keep the RabbitMQ clients on the same internal network as the RabbitMQ broker, and have the clients send HTTP requests to App Engine.